# o meu jqery apresenta sempre o erro "ocorreu um erro ao receber a mensagem"

Tags: jquery

```js
jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.mesg', function(e){
  if (e.which == 13) {
   var texto = $(this).innerHTML();
   var id = '$id:5';
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'msgamigos.php', 
    data: {mensagem: texto, de: id},
    success: function(retorno){
     if(retorno == 'ok'){
      $('.mesg').innerHTML('');
     }else{
      alert('Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem');
     }
    }
   });
  }else{alert('Ocorreu um erro ao receber a mensagem'); }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=\"mesg\" id=\"mesg\" tabindex=\"0\" contentEditable=\"true\" data-text=\"Publish Your news\" spellcheck=\"true\" aria-multiline=\"true\" style=\"color:grey;background:white;width:100%;height:19.5px;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid grey;\"></div></div></div></div>';
```

```html
<div class=\"mesg""id=\"mesg\" tabindex=\"0\" contentEditable=\"true\" data-text=\"Publish Your news\" spellcheck=\"true\" aria-multiline=\"true\" style=\"color:grey;background:white;width:100%;height:19.5px;vertical-align:middle;border-left:1px solid grey;\"></div></div></div></div>';
```

Comment: Tente usar isto : var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode; No lugar de e.which;

Comment: continua a não funcionar

Comment: mas pelo menos quando clico em qualquer tecla, ja nao aparece esse erro

Answer (score 0):

Tentei usar esse código com um campo do tipo INPUT e funcionou sem problema.
Não sei se com div isto deveria funcionar ...

```
<input class="mesg"/>

jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.mesg', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        console.log("ENTER OK");
        //... resto do código aqui
    }else{
        console.log("NÃO É ENTER");
        //... resto do código aqui
     }
});
```

Comment: tem de ser obrigatoriamente uma div não pode ser um input

Comment: Mas uma div não recebe valor escrito pelo que conheço, não podes criar um input dentro da div ? Pois simplesmente com DIV, acho que não é possivel.

Comment: recebe em innerHTML

Comment: @PedroFerreira Mas ele só recebe o valor depois de passar pela validação de tecla, que deve ser feita em um elemento input ...

Comment: não se a div tiver a oportunidade de ter um event que era isso especificamente que queria